# New entry on top instead of bottom in SharePoint Online List Datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, datasheet

I have a list in SharePoint Online where the newest entry has to be on top of the datasheet view, I like to have the NEW empty row on TOP and not on bottom by Default as shown in the below screenshot

[image: Datasheet View]

When the list grows we don't want to scroll down to create a new item. Is there any way to achieve this ?